# What is the best way to structure api config file in react project?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am developing react app and for api call i am using axios library. For all api calls i have app.js file, and then when some component needs to make api call just call function from that file. In short that would be little structre for now. In app.js file i have multiple api calls in which i am also seanding header config cause of token authorization. So i want to have a separate config file which will have default api header and all urls i am using for api call. I am looking for a best way to structure code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Component, which hold's your **baseURL** ( **API base location** )

**Base URL Component:**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://react-test-b1ae5.firebaseio.com/'
});

export default instance;
```

**Another file to hold you API calls part:** You can give this component a desired name (Ex: **axiousURL**)

```
export const ADD_URL = 'AddArticle';
export const DELETE_URL = 'DeleteArticle';
export const UPDATE_URL = 'UpdateArticle';
```

**Consuming:**

```
import axios from '../../axios-orders';
import * as axiosURLS from '../../axiosURL'; 

axios.get( axios.baseURL+axiosURLS.DELETE_URL )
            .then( response => {
                // Some code//
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                // handle error
            } );
```

Comment: that looks good but also i need a little upgrade: for example, i need to have axios with two diffrent headers, first one when i login, and then second one when i am doing some request i need to to send token authorization, so if i put header in axios.create i will have it for every axios call, and i dont need it for login

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **redux**, I would take a look in this lib [redux-api-middleware](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware).

I like to use it because it makes the code clear. Instead of use `axios`, it uses `fetch` to manage the requests.